# What is the convex hull of the rank-$k$ PSD matrix?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matrix-rank, convex-hulls

What is the convex hull (convex envelope) of the following non-convex set?$$\left\{X \succeq 0 \mid \mbox{rank}(X) = k \right\}$$

If we further require $X=VV^T$, where $V^T V = I$ and $V$ is $n \times k$. Then the convex hull of the above set is

$$\left\{X \mid 0 \preceq X \preceq I, \mbox{Trace}(X) = k \right\}$$

See [this](https://archive.org/details/onsumoflargestei00over). But for the general rank-$k$ PSD matrix, what is the convex hull?

This is an interesting problem, but it is still open.

Comment: Are $X$s symmetric?

Comment: From context (the use of the $\preceq$ operator, the semidefinite programming tag, $X=VV^T$) it is safe to assume symmetry.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thanks, I usually do, but one can never be sure...

Comment: I would think this is more of a homework question than an open problem? I would guess that the answer is the set of all $X\ge 0$ that have rank $\ge k$.

Comment: @copper.hat, fair enough. dsadkl, am I to understand you are asking Math.SE to solve an open research problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one assumes that  the $X$'s are Hermitian then there is a straightforward answer.

Let $E=\{ X | X \ge 0, X^* = X, \operatorname{rk} X = k \} $,
$G=\{ X | X \ge 0, X^* = X, \operatorname{rk} X \ge k \}$.

Then we have
$\operatorname{co} E = G$.

If $X_k \ge 0$ and $\lambda_k >0$, with $\sum_k \lambda_k = 1$, then
$\ker (\sum_k \lambda_k X_k) \subset \cap_k \ker X_k$. It follows that 
$\operatorname{rk}(\sum_k \lambda_k X_k) \ge k$ and so
$G$ is convex (showing $\sum_k \lambda_k X_k \ge 0$ is straightforward), and since we have
$E \subset G$ then $\operatorname{co} E \subset G$.

Now suppose $X \in G$. Let $r=\operatorname{rk} X$. If $r=k$ then $X \in E$, so suppose $r>k$. We can write
$X=U \Lambda U^*$, where $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag} \{ \lambda_1,...,\lambda_r,0,\cdots, 0 \}$ and $\lambda_i >0$.
We can write $\Lambda = {1 \over 2}\operatorname{diag} \{ \lambda_1,...,\lambda_{r-2},0,2\lambda_r,0,\cdots, 0 \} + {1 \over 2}\operatorname{diag} \{ \lambda_1,...,\lambda_{r-2},2\lambda_{r-1},0,0,\cdots, 0 \}$, so, by induction, it 
should be clear that we can write $\Lambda = \sum_p \mu_p \Lambda_p$,
where $\Lambda_p \in E$ and the $\mu_p$ are convex multipliers. Hence $X = \sum_p \mu_p U\Lambda_pU^* \in 
\operatorname{co} E$.

Depending on your definition, $G$ is, in fact, a convex cone. It does not include the 'point' $0$.

Comment: We only cosider the case that X is symmetric here.

Thanks a lot for the answer! 
Based on your result, I find that the convex hull is too large and it may be not very reasonable to use it to replace the original nonconvex set as the constraint. If we furter assume that $X\leq \alpha I$ for some positive $\alpha$, then what is the convex hull in this case? I guess it may be $\{X|0\leq X\leq \alpha I, Tr(X)=\alpha k\}$. What is your opinion? Thanks a lot!